# Select row in table via AJAX and display it (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have div where I need to display partial View via AJAX call to Controller

I have Table

Here is table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionBlocks] (
[Block_ID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Question1]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question2]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question3]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question4]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question5]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question6]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question7]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question8]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question9]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Question10]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Interview_Id] INT            NULL,
[QuestionId]   INT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Block_ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionBlocks_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([Interview_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Interviews] ([Interview_Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

I need to display row where Interview_Id will be `id`

Id is id from url. My url is like *****.***/Interwier/Recording/id

I wrote Action methods for PartialView

Here is code.

```
public ActionResult Recording(int id)
{
    /*var items = db.QuestionBlocks
        .Where(x => x.Interview_Id == id)
        .Select(x => x).ToList();*/
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    return View();
}

public ActionResult QuestionBlock(int id) {
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var questionblocks = db.QuestionBlocks.Take(id);
    return PartialView(questionblocks);
}
```

And here is AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/interwier/QuestionBlock",
        data: { id: rows_num = 1 },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#questions").html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Smth wrong in controller");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is PArtialView. But I think it is useless in this question

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartSolutions.Models.QuestionBlock>
@foreach (var item in Model) {  
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question1)
    </div>       
}
```

All that I need is get id from url, how I can do this?

Comment: The way I fixed this in one of my problem was to set Id to a session variable or a global variable in "public ActionResult Recording(int id)" method and use that variable "QuestionBlock"

Comment: I found way to get id from url via JS. It's looks like this `var url = window.location.pathname;
        var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/' + 1));`. Will now check , if it works as I expected. @devil_coder

Comment: Good Job @E.S Thanks

Comment: Look, my code gets all after localhost:5654. Will now make code to get only id @devil_coder

Comment: `var full_url = document.URL; // Get current url
        var url_array = full_url.split('/') // Split the string into an array with / as separator
        var last_segment = url_array[url_array.length - 1];  // Get the last part of the array (-1)
        alert(last_segment);`

This code is works perfectly. @devil_coder

Answer (score 1):

So I found answer

Here is code for getting id from url

```
var full_url = document.URL; // Get current url var url_array = full_url.split('/') // Split the string into an array with / as separator var last_segment = url_array[url_array.length - 1]; // Get the last part of the array (-1) alert(last_segment);
```

And Controller is left as-is